Monitors wake up without user interaction
I'm running a dual monitor setup and have been having problems getting them to stay suspended when I'm not using the computer. I first noticed that despite my Power settings set to blank the screens after five minutes, this feature would often stop working until I logged out of my account or rebooted the computer. As a workaround, I started locking the screen when I wanted to suspend the monitors, however I find that most mornings both monitors have come out of sleep mode. The screens are blank, but the backlights are on.
Does anyone know how I would go about troubleshooting this?
System specs:
   OS: Ubuntu 24.10
   Monitor 1: Samsung LC27JG52QQNXZA
   Monitor 2: ASUS ProArt Display PA278QV
   Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Super
   Driver: nvidia-driver-560-open
   Windowing system: Wayland
